# Sitecore - Is it possible to have target="_blank" on Image SXA Component

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-sxa

Is it possible to send user to another page, for example in this case `www.stackoverflow.com`, when user clicks on the image? Basically right now, when someone clicks on the image itself it does not send the user to another page, even though it has the `target="_blank"`, as you can see from the pictures.

Here is the first picture:

[image]

The link view:

[image]

This is the HTML that I get, as you can see there is not `target="_blank"` in console
[image]

Comment: Can you show the resulted html of the link?

Comment: @BETOMBO There you go, I updated the question

Comment: When you don’t specify the description the target blank is missing.  So the workaround is to add space to the description if you don’t have one.